# Scheme New-Sin-X Function

Tags: scheme, sum, trigonometry

I am writing a function named new-sin that has two parameters, x and n. I define factorial within the function because I am using it to calculate the denominator of the values output by the function. The function is supposed to return the first (n+1) terms of the power series evaluated at x. To be specific (new-sin x 3) is supposed to return x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5!-(x^7)/7!

My code is as follows:

```
(define (new-sin-x x n)
(define (factorial j)
  (if (= j 0) 1 (* j (factorial (- j 1)))))
    (if (= n 0)
     x
    (+ (* (expt -1 n) (/ (expt x (+ 1 (* 2 n))) (factorial(+ 1 (* n 2.0))) (new-sin-x x       (- n 1 )))))))

(new-sin-x 1 3)
```

Is (new-sin-x x (- n 1 ) supposed to be written outside of the addition statement or is it right the way it is?

Comment: You really should invest in a free editor that helps you with proper indentation and parenthesis matching. If you did you would have seen the + only had one term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of syntax errors (misplaced parentheses, to be sure). This should work:

```
(define (new-sin-x x n)
  (define (factorial j)
    (if (= j 0)
        1
        (* j (factorial (- j 1)))))
  (if (= n 0)
      x
      (+ (* (expt -1 n)
            (/ (expt x (+ 1 (* 2 n)))
               (factorial (+ 1 (* 2.0 n)))))
         (new-sin-x x (- n 1)))))
```

These kinds of errors can be easily detected, you just have to:

1. Correctly indent your code
2. Properly match parentheses
3. Use a good IDE that helps you with 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Oscar's fixed version of the original, with optimizations.

```
(define (new-sin-x x n)
 (let ((x (inexact->exact x)))
  (define n-odd-fact ;;cheating here calculates the next odd factorial.
    (let ((last-value 1))  ;;but real memiozation shouldn't be that hard
      (lambda (j)
        (begin (set! last-value (* j (- j 1) last-value))
               last-value)))) ;;memioze(ish) last call
  (let loop ((i 0) (sum x))
    (let ((term (if (= i 0)
                    0
                    (* (if (odd? i) -1 1)
                       (/ (expt x (+ 1 (* 2 i)))
                          (n-odd-fact (+ 1 (* 2 i))))))))
       (if (= i n)
           sum
           (loop (+ i 1) (+ sum term)))))))  ;;tail call here
```

Comment: It's not my own :P I just fixed OP's (un)matching parentheses

Comment: Corrected to represent.

Comment: You'll get an error here when n is large and x is inexact as the fib number get beyond what can be expressed in a floating point fairly quickly. Fortunately n=20 gives very good accuracy.